# Catching Any DoesNotExist Error

Tags: python, django, django-errors

I am using Django 1.7. Normally you can catch `DoesNotExist` exception over your model like;

```
try:
   ...
except model.DoesNotExist, den:
   ...
```

I want to catch any `DoesNotExist` exception. I really don't want to care about its model. Actually, I really don't know which model `DoesNotExist` is passing through the code piece either. I mean, I am not able to know the model.

So I have to catch any `DoesNotExist` error somehow.

Is there a way to catch any `DoesNotExist` error in `Django`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`DoesNotExist` exceptions are subclasses of [`django.core.exceptions.ObjectDoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/exceptions/#objectdoesnotexist):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

try:
    # ...
except ObjectDoesNotExist as den:
    # handle exception
```